# Jquery on('click') with dynamic button ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dynamic

I have a comment's reply form which is loop through database, each of the form and reply button are dynamically assigned with difference ID, such as `<button type="button" id="btn_reply_comment_'.$row['id'].'">Post Reply</button>` as well as a form ID with `<form id="reply_form_'.$row['id'].'">`.

I want to make an ajax call trigger by the `#btn_reply_comment_{follow by dynamic ID}`, but I cannot assign dynamic ID to match with which button is clicked, how can it be done?

**Jquery to trigger ajax by button click:**

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn_reply_comment_'+id, function(){
    var parameters = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

    alert(parameters);

    //ajax call here

});
```

Comment: assign a class attribute to the nodes, and listen on the class.

Comment: can you elaborate more? or working sample in my codes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a class for this. And set up the click handler on teh class.

So your HTML might look like:

```
<button type="button" id="btn_reply_comment_'.$row['id'].'" class="post_reply_button">Post Reply</button>
```

And your jQuery would look like:

```
$('body').on('click', '.post_reply_button', function(){
    var parameters = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

    alert(parameters);

    //ajax call here

});
```

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<button id="btn_reply_comment_'.$row['id'].'" class="className">Post Reply</button>
```

jquery

```
$(".className").click(function(){
    var parameters = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

    alert(parameters);

    //ajax call here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stash the ID on the elements themselves. No need to use string manipulation.

HTML

```
"<button type="button" class="btn_reply_comment" data-rowid="'.$row['id'].'">"
"<form id="reply_form" data-rowid="'.$row['id'].'">"
```

Javascript

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn_reply_comment', function(){
    var rowId = $(this).data('rowid'),
        parameters = $('form[data-rowid=' +rowId + ']').serialize();

    alert(parameters);

    //ajax call here

});
```